Identify the closure, interior and boundary of the next convex set
I must find the boundary, closure and interior of this set
\begin{equation*}
S = \{\mathbb{x}: x_1 + x_2 \leq 5, -x_1 + x_2 + x_3\leq 7,x_1,x_2,x_3\geq0 \}
\end{equation*}
For the closure, i plan to proof that the set is closed. But I feel that my reasoning is wrong, i take a convergent sequence in $S$ with the shape $\{x^{(n)} \}$ such that:
\begin{equation*}
x^{(n)} = ({x_1}^{(n)},{x_2}^{(n)},{x_3}^{(n)}) \to (x_1,x_2,x_3) = x
\end{equation*}
how the sequence is in the set:
\begin{equation*}
{x_1}^{(n)} + {x_2}^{(n)}\leq 5, -{x_1}^{(n)} + {x_2}^{(n)} + {x_3}^{(n)}\leq 7,{x_1}^{(n)},{x_2}^{(n)},{x_3}^{(n)} \geq 0
\end{equation*}
and taking the limit
\begin{equation*}
x_1 + x_2 \leq 5, -x_1 + x_2 + x_3\leq 7,x_1,x_2,x_3\geq0
\end{equation*}
This probably doesn't make sense but that's why I'm looking for help, I'm also very interested in the interior and the closure (it's best to use that $bs \ S = \overline{S}-int \ S $)

For a set defined by continuous functions of the coordinates, basically the loose inequalities will result in a closed set and the strict ones into an open set.
The sequence characterisation you used, is clearly making usage of that continuity.
The boundary though is harder to describe, you may want to compute the intersections of the planes two by two, and use these lines to describe the resulting "polygons" (I put quotes, because since you have only $3$ planes it is not bounded, and some of the polygons are  not proper ones).
I see no easy way to write the boundary (it'll be tedious unions of a mix of loose inequalities and equalities).
